# PGP Encryption causes program to crash after Multiple File Encryptions

Tags: c#, encryption, console-application, bouncycastle, pgp

I have followed the code in [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Pretty-Good-Privacy-using-4f473c67/view/Discussions) to build a console application which encrypt multiple files at once.

With the application I am encrypting bulk amount of files (Max I tried is 4). What I noticed is after 2nd or 3rd file encryption, the program closes itself without any error. This happened in both Debug and Release environments.

I could not figure it out why. Anybody have any idea?

I implemented a helper class on top of it and it reads as:

```
namespace PgPSignAndEncryption.Helper
{
    public class PgPHelperClass
    {
        private string JKSBPublicKey = PgPSignAndEncryptionForCiti.Properties.Settings.Default.PgPPublicKeyPath;
        private string JKSBPrivateKey = PgPSignAndEncryptionForCiti.Properties.Settings.Default.PgPPrivateKeyPath;
        private string JKSBSecretKey = "MySecretKey";

        private string _encryptedFileName = string.Empty;
        private string _decryptedFileName = string.Empty;

        public string EncryptedFileName
        {
            get { return _encryptedFileName; }
            set { _encryptedFileName = value; }
        }
        public string DecryptedFileName
        {
            get { return _decryptedFileName; }
            set { _decryptedFileName = value; }
        }

        public void KeyGeneration()
        {
            #region PublicKey and Private Key Generation 

            PgPSignAndEncryption.KeyGeneration.KeysForPGPEncryptionDecryption.GenerateKey("Me", "MySecretKeys", @"C:\Keys\");
            //Console.WriteLine("Keys Generated Successfully");

            #endregion
        }

        public void Encryption()
        {
            try
            {
                #region PGP Encryption 

                PgpEncryptionKeys encryptionKeys = new PgpEncryptionKeys(this.JKSBPublicKey, this.JKSBPrivateKey, this.JKSBSecretKey);
                PgpEncrypt encrypter = new PgpEncrypt(encryptionKeys);

                var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.DecryptedFileName);
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.DecryptedFileName);
                var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.DecryptedFileName);
                this.EncryptedFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}.gpg", path, fileName, ext);

                using (Stream outputStream = File.Create(this.EncryptedFileName))
                {
                    encrypter.EncryptAndSign(outputStream, new FileInfo(this.DecryptedFileName));
                }

                //EncryptedFileName = this.EncryptedFileName;

                #endregion
            } //<<<<<<<<<------ It crashes after this point!
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                EncryptedFileName = er.Message;
            }  
        }

        public void Decryption(out string DecryptedFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                #region PGP Decryption 

                var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(this.EncryptedFileName);
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.EncryptedFileName);
                var ext = string.Empty;
                //try
                //{
                //    var aExt = fileName.Split('.');
                //    fileName = aExt.First();
                //    ext = aExt.Last();
                //}
                //catch (Exception)
                //{
                //    ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.EncryptedFileName);
                //}
                this.DecryptedFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.out", path, fileName);

                PGPDecrypt.Decrypt(this.EncryptedFileName, this.JKSBPrivateKey, this.JKSBSecretKey, this.DecryptedFileName);

                DecryptedFileName = this.DecryptedFileName;

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                DecryptedFileName = er.Message;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is how I call in my Console App

```
private static void BulkFileEncryption()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(PickUpFolderPath))
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(DropFolderPath);
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    //Encryption and Decryption
                    helper.DecryptedFileName = file;

                    helper.Encryption();
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File Encrypted: {0}", file));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint insinde the try block and step through. Then you should be able to inspect the exception message and type as well as stack trace. Add those information to the question.

Comment: Thank you @Fildor. I did, as you can see in `public void Encryption()` I had `try-catch` block and had breakpoints to it but strangely it simply crashes (closes the console app itself) before going to the 'catch` block. It simply does not throw an error.

Comment: The crash could be I/O or hardware related since from what you describe a generic .NET exception is not being thrown. Are the files successfully encrypted and signed?

Comment: Oh, wow. That's a nose-dive... Do you have something that could be related in the Windows Event Logs?

Comment: Please try while disabling your virus scanner temporarily. I've had McAfee mess up many results (including builds of my security related software!!!) - although McAfee is the shittiest virus scanner out there, other virus scanners may also block access and trigger errors I suppose.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner Thank you for that. I did check I did not find anything concerning; Everything got signed and encrypted but the cursor did not move to next command subsequently.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes You gave a good point! I had Kaspersky in mine and I disabled and then tried, then the process worked well without any crash. Let me go do more rounds of testing to be absolutely be sure of it.

Comment: @Fildor Did not find anything concerning in the Logs even :(

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I found TrendMicro to be even shittier. We had a system, where it would check if a Server is online and running by having it listen on a TCP port, then have the client open a TCP connection and closing it again. Guess what: TrendMicro answered the connection attempt. Took us days to find out why the test would succeed even if the Server Software wasn't running.

Comment: Perhaps the antimalware services are implementing a guard against ransomware? I'm guessing if so then they are killing the violating process explicitly, which explains why no exception is thrown nor handled.

Comment: It was detected that Kaspersky is blocking the process. It some times deletes the File, thinking it does a malicious task. Check here: https://imgur.com/4GbBWXZ